# MySQL - creating my.cnf file from loaded config

Tags: mysql, linux, my.cnf

Is it somehow possible to generate a config file `my.cnf` from the running MySQL server?

I have accidentally removed our my.cnf file and I need to re-create it in an honorable fashion.

Instead of `nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf` I went `rm /etc/mysql/my.cnf`.

Days like these...

Comment: Try this and see if it helps http://ngeneric.com/tutorials/system/linux/messed-mycnf-or-accidentally-deleted-it-here-how-generate-it

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, problem is that I did not install mysql through apt-get. I'm running MySQL version 5.6 and it is not available for Debian Squeeze through apt-get. I installed the `.deb` file from mysql.com

Comment: Hmm `Squeeze` is pretty old it `wheezy` now, check if you can find the something for `sources.list` to update and do `apt-get`

Answer (score 0):

Try: nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf and put these values.

```
[client]
user = DBUSERNAME
password = DBPASSWORD
host = DBSERVER

[mysql]
database = DBNAME
```

Where DBUSERNAME, DBPASSWORD, DBSERVER and 
DBNAME should be replaced with your own correct database username, database hostname, database name and database password. You will not have any of these until you create a database through your Control Panel.